# Resolve circular import error in python

Tags: python, class, python-import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

I have class B that imports and creates instances of class A.
Class A needs reference to B in its contructor and so includes B.

```
from a import A
class B:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = A()
```

---

```
from b import B
class A:
  def __init__(self, ref):
    assert isinstance(ref, B)
    self.ref = ref
```

This doesn't work. The main file imports B and uses it... not.
Something with the imports is wrong.

Error from file a
**ImportError: cannot import name B**

Comment: No, that doesn't work. So, don't do that.

Comment: Not an answer but it is probably best to have a better design which doesn't require this circular import.

Comment: Understood. But this seems like a basic problem. Class needs reference to upper level...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apart from "don't do that, you are painting yourself into a corner", you could also postpone the import of B until you need it. File `a.py`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, ref):
        from b import B
        assert isinstance(ref, B)
        self.ref = ref
```

Class `B` won't be imported until you instantiate class `A`, by which time the module already has been imported fully by module `b`.

You can also use a common base class and test for that.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with that. I somewhere saw this idea but couldn't understand. Your additional explanation is excellent!

Answer (score 3):

Just import classes in `__init__` method

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, ref):
      from b import B
      assert isinstance(ref, B)
      self.ref = ref
```

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` method executes when you create an instance of the class. In this case, you should get it to work by simply changing the import statements like this:

```
import a 
class B:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = a.A(self)
```

---

```
import b
class A:
  def __init__(self, ref):
    assert isinstance(ref, b.B)
    self.ref = ref
```