# How to resolve circular dependency when using composition?

Tags: python, oop, circular-dependency, circular-reference, cyclic-reference

I came across some situation like shown below, where each class needs the other class and it creates the cyclic dependency. I came across this type of situation while wrapping some C code using ctypes.
There already are lots of post on this topic but I didn't find them helpful, I need some example.

***Module A***:

```
from B import C2

class C1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "C1"
        self.c2 = C2()
```

***Module B***

```
from A import C1

class C2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "C2"
        self.c1 = C1()
```

***Main***

```
from A import C1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    o = C1()
    print(o.name)
```

Comment: This code contains an infinite recursion:  The `__init__()` method of `C1` unconditionally calls the `__init__()` of `C2` and vice versa.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolve circular import error in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027011/resolve-circular-import-error-in-python). My example here is essentially the same as my answer there.

Answer (score 5):

Solutions (assuming the inifinite recursion is resolved):

1. Avoid this kind of circular dependency.
2. Put the interdependent components into the same module.
3. Use `import A` and `import B` instead of the `from ...` form.  (This might fail in certain situations if packages are involved.)
4. Use function-level imports.

Answer (score 2):

Change Module B to not import class `C1` until the last possible moment, inside the `__init__.py`:

```
class C2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        from A import C1
        self.name = "C2"
        self.c1 = C1()
```

Note that because `C1` instantiates `C2` and vice-versa, you'll end up with an infinite recursion problem, but I'll charitably assume that you don't have that problem outside of your illustration example.

Answer (score 1):

That's a circular dependancy in any language, in fact it's an infinite recursion

Take c2 out of c1 and c1 out of c2

```
from B import C2 
from A import C1

class C3(object):
  def __init__(self):         
    self.c1 = C1() 
    self.c2 = C2()
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a Circular import error, remove the import statement from MODULE B -> "from A import C1".

import 'C1' where you need(inside the method).

**Like this -** 
from B import C2

class C1(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.name = "C1"
    self.c2 = C2()
```

class C2(object):

```
def __init__(self): 
    import A.C1
    self.name = "C2"
    self.c1 = C1()
```