# Django management cannot import method from app

Tags: python, django, python-import, importerror

I have a django app that's file tree looks like this:

- app1

  - ____init____.py
  - functions.py
  - management (dir)

    - ____init____.py
    - excel.py
    - commands (dir)

      - ____init____.py
      - importfromexcel.py

I have my most used methods in functions.py, and I want to use them in excel.py (from app1.functions import method1, method1, method3) , but here comes the issue.

When I run it like `python manage.py importfromexcel`, it works. But when I try to run the migrations with `python manage.py migrate` it gives import error:

```
    File "PATH_TO_DJANGO\app1\management\excel.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app1.functions import method1, method1, method3
    ImportError: cannot import name method1
```

What is wrong with my import? How should I import it if not this way?

Comment: I'd guess it's a circular import error but need to see more code to make sure - Take a gander at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10027101/784648

Comment: Thank you for the guide, it was really a circular import, I did not know about this. It is now solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd guess it's a circular import error but need to see more code to make sure - Take a gander at [stackoverflow.com/a/10027101/784648](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10027101/784648) - @ARJMP