# ImportError: cannot import name 'DogeClient' from partially initialized module 'dogehouse' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python

So basically I was trying to write a bot for dogehouse.tv and I can't even start due to the error, I've spoken to some other people and they seem to have no problems regarding this. Here is the code:

```
from dogehouse import DogeClient, event

class Client(DogeClient):
    @event
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Ready")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Client("token", "refresh_token").run()
```

Error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'DogeClient' from partially initialized module 'dogehouse' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: Is `dogehouse` a module you wrote, or a third-party module?

Comment: Don't name your file `dogehouse.py`

Comment: All the way to the moon

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this : [Stackoverflow: Resolve circular import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027011/resolve-circular-import-error-in-python)

I've seen similar error in Django, you might have initialized the class in init or some other file which is causing this error.